# Which tag for a distributed interactive simulation question?

Tags: discussion, tags

I want to create a question related to [distributed interactive simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Interactive_Simulation).

The `dis` tag is missing, so I wanted to create one by myself. I've tried `distributed-interactive-simulation` but it's too long. Instead `dis` appear too short for me, and I don't know if is right to use it.

Which tag(s) should I use?

Comment: Tags are means for the answerers to find questions they are interested to answer, if you create a new tag, is pretty likely that no one that is able to answer your question will find it.

Comment: And what if there's no tag that represent my argument?

Comment: You are on a programming site, asking a programming question. It's very difficult that you don't have either language, library, framework, tool.

Comment: A sufficiently on topic question will be able to reference a chosen framework/library/language, your current results, your expected results, and any context necessary to understand the code you've written and are having trouble with. Those types of tools and topics are the tags you want, not a broad category.